# Maven can not import dependencies between modules

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-module

I have Maven-based project, where are several modules(`Spring-Boot` projects).Structure

```
project
|__contract-user
|____pom.xml
|__user
|____pom.xml
|__service2
|____pom.xml
|__pom.xml
```

So, classic structure. In contract-user service I placed some common entities and Feign Clients, because they are used both in user and service2. Here are poms:

root pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>contract-user</module>
        <module>service2</module>
        <module>user</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>project</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
        <compiler.plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler.plugin.version>
        <source.version>1.9</source.version>
        <target.version>1.9</target.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--  versions higher than 5.1.2 does not work-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.lognet</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-testing</artifactId>
            <version>1.59.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- gRPC dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.59.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.59.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.59.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Utils-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${source.version}</source>
                    <target>${target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netflix-candidates</id>
            <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
            <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

contract-user pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>contract-user</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>contract-user</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <description>contract-user</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

user pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>user</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>user</name>
    <description>user</description>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Project modules dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>contract-user</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
            
        <!--                Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        Security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--                Database&tools-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongock-springboot-v3</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-springdata-v4-driver</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.2.BETA</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

In user service class with path: `/project/user/src/main/java/com/project/user/security/service/AuthService.java`

I have import:

```
import com.project.contractuser.dto.TokenValidationRequestDTO;
```

so Idea does not underline this import, sees it. But when I run application, Maven says during compile stage:

```
package com.project.contractuser.dto does not exist
```

Same thing with other contract-user imported classes. I tried to do mvn clean install, but it failed with same error. I deleted `.idea folder`, my local `.m2 folder`, invalidated cache. I I unsigned and segned maven project, I reloaded project and refreshed dependencies.
But have no effect. I also have one more contract service, and other services dont recognize its classes. This makes me crazy..

What I'm doing wrong? Why Maven cant manage classes?(in settings I set bunled(Maven 3) - Version 3.8.1)

Comment: Few information here. Did you check the contents of the contract-user-JAR in your local Maven-repository? Does it contain the expected classes? Besides: In Maven version numbers without trailing -SNAPSHOT are reserved for Maven release builds. During development you'd rather use 1.0-SNAPSHOT and so on.

Comment: You have added the spring-boot-maven-plugin to your root pom which means you inherit to all childs which results in building spring boot jars which are not consumable jars... Add the spring boot maven plugin only there where your main class which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` is located...

Comment: @Karsten what do you mean? .m2/repository folder?

Comment: @Sam Fisher Yes. As of your GAV coordinate it's in `.m2/repository/com/project/contract-user`

Comment: @Karsten checked all the classes in that .jar. they present. so Maven correctly builds contract-user

Comment: @khmarbaise all modules are spring-boot applications. I removed spring-boot-maven-plugin from parent pom, added only to user and service2 poms and it worked! but appeared another problem. I have feign clients in contract services and I use them in user service(there I inject them in constructor). so when I start user service it fails with error parameter of constructor could not be found. how can I solve this?